# 12 digit Regex for Phone number

Tags: php, regex

I an trying to get a regex for a phone number with exactly 12 digits in the format: +############.

Code i am trying to use is `([+]?)\d{12}(\d{2})?$` but no luck.

Please help

Comment: try regex `\+\d{12}`

Comment: Are you trying to allow extra digits on the end? If so, what are the criteria for those?

Comment: @duskwuff no I want exact 12 digits and the + at the beginning is required i.e 123123123123 should not be allowed since the + is missing

Comment: @user38208 the poster of your selected answer has edited your post to suit his/her answer.  YOU need to edit your question to provide the correct question details for YOUR task.

Comment: @mickmackusa I think the objective of stackoverflow is to contribute, isn't it ? Isn't it legit to edit a question when the op might be struggling to describe it properly due to many probable reason ?

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman It is also legit for me to rollback an edit and I am tempted to rollback the question edit, because there was absolutely no mention of optional trailing digits in the plain English of the original post written by the OP.  The failed pattern could have come from anywhere and OPs who don't understand regex are capable of throwing all kinds of rubbish into a pattern without understanding what it does.  A quality contribution would drill down into what the OP is actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I have rolled back the edit. At no point did the OP suggest that the added two digits were intended.

Comment: @duskwuff in my opinion (\d{2})? is the point in his attempt where the OP suggested that there can be optional 2 digits

Comment: The OP also had an optional + in the original pattern.  The user seems to command English, not necessarily regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
^\+\d{12}(\d{2})?$
```

You needed to escape the plus sign

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nX5XnH/2/)

Comment: I want exact 12 digits and the + at the beginning is required i.e 123123123123 should not be allowed since the + is missing

Comment: Then you just needed to remove the ? sign after the \+ . ? means optional  . updated the answer

Comment: @user38208  Accepting this answer means your question is poorly constructed or you don't know what a correct regex pattern looks like -- this will surely confuse future readers.

Comment: @mickmackusa I also guessed the final two optional digits. Updated the question for future readers

Comment: Often people who supply their failed patterns cannot distinguish between a refined/optimized pattern and one that merely provides a correct outcome.  It is best not to assume the optional two digits at the end, specifically because there is no mention of it in the plain English of the question.

Comment: Using the OP's provided input string, this will also work "perfectly": `^\+\d{12}(unrefined pattern)?$`

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will match exactly 12 digits after a plus sign:

```
/^\+\d{12}$/
```

What is your trailing optional `(/d{2})?` component doing in your pattern?

---

This is the same functionality without regex:

```
$phone='+012345678912';
if($phone[0]=='+' && strlen($phone)==13 && is_numeric(substr($phone,1))){
    echo 'valid';
}else{
    echo 'invalid';
}
// displays: valid
```

Comment: @user38208 My answer does exactly what you are asking for.  If this is not working for you, please clarify your question.

Answer (score -1):

Do we need to capture certain digits/sequences or are you just validating its a number with that format?

I use this online tool [regex101](https://regex101.com/) whenever I'm unsure of regex. It shows on the right exactly what you're capturing/checking which is very useful. Depending on your use case, I don't see how this regex doesn't work, please provide an example. Otherwise:

1. You're only capturing the + sign and the 2 digits after the initial 12.
2. You anchor to the end of the string and not the beginning
3. Both the + and 2 extra numerals are optional but you wanted to get the +############  exact?

I suggest you use `\+(\d{12})` and avoid using anchors and capture groups you do not require.

Answer (score -1):

## If you want to support optional spaces between sets of three numbers, you would use this regex instead

```
^(\+)(\d{3}\s?){4}(\d{2})?$
```

where `\s` is a **space** character and `?` means **optional**

https://regex101.com/r/nX5XnH/3 (demo)

```
+012 345 678 912 (ok)
+012345 678 912 (ok)
+012 345678912 (ok)
+01234567891244 (ok)
012345678913 (no mach - missing plus sign)
```